# load webstorage from native sqlite

Tags: sqlite, html

I have a native sqlite database and i want to load/read it through HTML5 webstorage. But I am unable to do that. I already tried it by placing the file in the same folder and running the below script.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Search </title>
<script>
var db = null;
function startapp(){
db = window.openDatabase("artistsWcities.sqlite", '1.0', 'Test', 19 * 1024 * 1024);
if (db) {
alert("database loaded");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startapp()">
</body>
</html>
```

But it created new file instead of reading new one. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In W3C [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-opendatabase) `openDatabase` constructor apply first argument only like browser database name, not any filename. Specification quote:

> The user agent must act as if the database was hosted in an otherwise
>   completely empty environment with no resources. For example, attempts
>   to read from or write to the file system will fail.

You can get sqlite file from local resources only in browser extensions or components, for example in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage).

You get your file `artistsWcities.sqlite` by request from server, for example, AJAX and in success callback past it to browser local database. More info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481667/html5-load-web-sql-db-from-local-file).

But if your code example is from extension for browser, read closely the documentation. If Firefox extension you can load local database via:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["my_db_file_name.sqlite"]);
let mDBConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file); // Will also create the file if it does not exist
```